# sympy pretty print in Rmarkdown

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, sympy, reticulate

Is it possible to include pretty formatted formulae from sympy in a python chunk in an r-markdown document using reticulate. If I use `init_printing` it prints the formula as ascii art, setting `use_latex="mathjax"` or `use_latex=True` has no effect.

Are there any arguments to `init_printing` or chunk options for the python chunk or `reticulate` options to get pretty formulae?

Here's a minimal example:

````
---
title: "rmd_sympy_reprex"
author: "snaut"
date: "11/23/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = TRUE)
```

```{python, include=FALSE}
from sympy import *
init_printing()
```

```{python}
omega = Symbol("omega")
x = Symbol("n", real=True)
Integral(x, (x,0,1))
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Yes! You can find the solution here:

https://cerebralmastication.com/2020/07/27/using-python-sympy-in-a-python-code-chunk-in-rmarkdown/

Here is the following reproducible example:

````
```{r}

library(reticulate)
```
```{python, results='asis'}

import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
polynomial = (2*x + 3)**4
output = polynomial.expand()
print('$' + sympy.printing.latex(output) + '$')
```
````

The idea is to use `sympy.printing.latex`. Then concatenate `'$'` at the beginning and at the end of the string. Finally use the option `results='asis'` in the python chunk.

[image]